# Removing Ubuntu 18.04 in Windows 10 WSL

Tags: windows-10

I have removed Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows 10 WSL but I am not sure if all the files have been deleted or not. How to be sure that all files are deleted?

Comment: What directories have you looked at?

Comment: First, run this command `wsl --list`.  Is the distro on this list?  Second.. 
Look in C:\Users\<mr_you>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu<wildcard>  Do you see a folder there?  If so, is there anything in it?